# Can I Push Remotes So That They Are Included When The Repo Is Cloned?

Tags: git, github, git-clone, git-remote

**Can I push remotes so that if someone clones the repo, the remotes are included and therefore already set up for them?**

It seems that a standard `git push` doesn't do this.

The git docs [here](http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-5.html) hint that this is possible:

> If you’ve cloned your repository, you should at least see origin

But I see nothing in the dos for `remote` [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) or `push` [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `origin` is automatically created when you clone, pointing to the clone URL, but that's it. In your own local repository, remotes are stored in `.git/config`; the only thing in `.git` that is ever transmitted is your history.

If you want to provide others with useful configuration, your best bet is to put it on a supplemental website or add a small script to your repository that others can execute to add configuration. Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
git config remote.blargh.url https://...
git config remote.blargh.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/blargh/*
```